# sorting a dictionary based on specific key value

Tags: python-2.7

I get data from the a source which I store in variable `d`

```
d = {
 '0174': 
    {
    'exists': 'Yes',
    'order': 4, 
    }, 
'0171': 
    {
    'order': 1, 
    }, 
'0080': {
    'exists': 'Yes', 
    'order': 0, 
    }, 
'0173': 
    {
        'exists': 'No', 
        'order': 3, 
    }, 
'0172': 
        { 
        'exists': 'Yes',
        'order': 2, 
        }
}
```

I have written the below logic that somewhat works,

```
for w in sorted(d, key=d.get, reverse=True):
    print(w, d[w]["shot_order"])
```

but not perfect.

I want to be able to sort based on the order `key` in the `dict`
please help.

Comment: question is python 2.7 specific , I want to achieve print based on order key !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `key=lambda outer_key: d[outer_key]['order']` as the sorting key:

```
for w in sorted(d, key=lambda outer_key: d[outer_key]['order'], reverse=True):
    print(w)
```

Outputs

```
0174
0173
0172
0171
0080
```